# Create a package in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-packages, dart-packages

How do I create a package in the new Dart Editor?

There is no "Add Pub support" checkbox?

Also how to create "packages" with the new editor?

Is a tutorial out there that describes the process with the new Editor?

Answer (score 13):

To create a package named mypackage.

For Dart package:

```
dart  create --template=package-simple  mypackage
```

For Flutter package:

```
flutter create --template=package mypackage
```

Comment: interestingly you answered a question from 2013 for Dart 1...you are aware of that :D

Comment: I tried dart create with templates package and package-simple; the results were the same.

Answer (score 5):

From the Dart/Flutter Documentation:

Step 1: Create the package
To create a Flutter package, use the --template=package flag with flutter create:

`flutter create --template=package hello`

This creates a package project in the hello folder with the following content:

```
LICENSE
A (mostly) empty license text file.

test/hello_test.dart
The unit tests for the package.

hello.iml
A configuration file used by the IntelliJ IDEs.

.gitignore
A hidden file that tells Git which files or folders to ignore in a project.

.metadata
A hidden file used by IDEs to track the properties of the Flutter project.

pubspec.yaml
A yaml file containing metadata that specifies the package’s dependencies. Used by the pub tool.

README.md
A starter markdown file that briefly describes the package’s purpose.

lib/hello.dart
A starter app containing Dart code for the package.

.idea/modules.xml, .idea/modules.xml, .idea/workspace.xml**
A hidden folder containing configuration files for the IntelliJ IDEs.

CHANGELOG.md
A (mostly) empty markdown file for tracking version changes to the package.
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no such possibilty in the Dart Editor for now. To create a package follow these steps :

- create an *New Application* `mylib` without *sample content*
- add a `pubspec.yaml` file
- add a `lib` folder
- create a `mylib.dart` containing the code you want to package

See the [Package layout conventions](https://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html) for more informations.

Comment: i did all of that, if i install over pub => success but cant use it in other apps, if i deploy it (error no web folder) if i add the web folder it deploys but still cant use the package?

Comment: _pub install_ will not allow you to use it in other apps. This command only creates `packages` directory in several places to allow Dart files to run when dependencies are defined. See [pub install doc](https://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pub-install.html). Locally you can use a [path package](https://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#path-packages).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dart project following the [**flutter way**](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) that allow you to auto generate the structure and the hierarchy of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to create a package in DART:

**Step 1: Create the package**

```
$ flutter create --template=package hello
```

**Step 2: Implement the package**

For pure Dart packages, simply add the functionality inside the main lib/.dart file, or in several files in the lib directory.

To test the package, add unit tests in a test directory.

For additional details on how to organize the package contents, see the Dart library package documentation:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Comment: interestingly you answered a question from 2013 for Dart 1...you are aware of that :D

Comment: It's a mistake to think of this as erroneously answering a question for Dart 1.0.  New Dart users who want to know how to create a Dart library will come across this and be happy to find this up-to-date answer.  What do they care that the question was originally asked in 2013?

Answer (score -1):

Any dart app is a package. To create a new Dart app use:

```
dart create my_package
```